# Kubernetes- Helm upgrade not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to upgrade one of my chart. But the changes which I have made in the "deployment.yaml" template in the chart is not there after the upgrade. I added the following lines in the spec of my kubernetes deployment.yaml file

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT
      value: "1"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MAX_IDLE_TIME_EXCESS_CONNECTIONS
      value: "10"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE
      value: "2"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MIN_POOL_SIZE
      value: "1"
```

I tried upgrading using the following command

helm upgrade ironic-molly spring-app-0.1.2.tgz --recreate-pods

Where "**ironic-molly**" is the release-name and **spring-app-0.1.2.tgz** is my chart with changes.

Helm output says that the package is upgraded, but the changes which i have made is missing in the deployment.yaml. What might be causing this issue.?

Regards,

Muhammed Roshan

Comment: look at the deployment from cluster `kubectl get deploy <deploymnet name> -o yaml` see it has the entry.

Comment: No. it does not have these entries. That is the issue I am facing. Upgrade is successful, but the changes are not getting reflected in the deployments.

Answer (score 1):

(If the problem is not with indents - adding an answer that also matches the title in general).

---

A few points to consider when you upgrade your helm charts:

1 ) Add the `--debug` to the `helm upgrade` command.

2 ) Check the current values of the specific resource - for example deployment: 
`kubectl get deploy <deploymnet name> -o yaml`.

3 ) Check latest events: `kubectl get events -n <namespace>`.

4 ) Check latest logs: `kubectl logs -l name=myLabel`.

5 ) If you want to ensure that pods are re-created - add a specific timestamp via annotation:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s-dashboard
      annotations:
        timestamp: "{{ date "20060102150405" .Release.Time }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax (indents)

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT
      value: "1"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MAX_IDLE_TIME_EXCESS_CONNECTIONS
      value: "10"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE
      value: "2"
    - name: LOGBACK_DB_MIN_POOL_SIZE
      value: "1"
```

should do the trick

Comment: Syntax is correct. Its a mistake I made while posting the questions. Actuall issue is something else. When I am doing a "--dry-run  --debug" of the upgrade, its actually showing me the values. But when I do the real upgrade, then only the value is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with your indents. I tested with my cluster it works. env tag should start same place as image: in your example it start below containers.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: envtest
        release: ugly-lizzard
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: envtest
          image: "nginx:stable"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: SSHD
            value: disalbe
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried some testing. I removed my spring-app deployment and did a fresh install of my Helm package, now I am able to see the modified values. Now if I try an upgrade (helm upgrade) of my helm chart after adding some new values in deployment.yaml, I am not seeing newly added values, even though Helm upgrade is showing successful. If there is an issues with my deployment.yaml syntax, then Ideally it should not work even when I am doing a "helm install" , right?

Comment: Correct , I am facing the same issue . With install everything work but with upgrade , its upgraded sucessfully , but nothing change in deployment.yml